# Initial zoom not working in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have imported `zoom` like this

```
import {zoom} from 'd3-zoom';
```

My `svg` and group `container` look something like this

```
const svg = select(root)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

const container = svg.append('g');
const zoomScale = 2;
```

I tried to set an initial zoom level (via `zoom().scaleTo()` function like this

```
zoom().scaleTo(container, zoomScale)
```

or like this

```
container.call(zoom().scaleTo, zoomScale)
```

But nothing is reflected back.
Interestingly the zoom function works , which looks like this

```
svg.call(
  zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    const transformation = getEvent().transform;
    const {x, y, k} = transformation;
    container.attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})scale(${k})`);
  })
);
```

Adding initial zoom by adding transform in my container works as well, but on the next zoom trigger, zoom starts off with value 1 and a flicker sort of thing is seen in the whole chart. I wish to avoid that.

What is wrong here ? please help .

Comment: First set a variable using the event handler you described in your question, like `var zoom = zoom().on('zoom', () => { const transformation etc...` and then use it: `zoom.scaleTo(container, zoomScale)`. Also, do the same to the SVG: `svg.call(zoom);`, just that.

Comment: OMG!!! This worked thank you soo very much, please answer the thread and I shall mark it as correct. Would you also mind explaining a bit that how this works and mine version don't. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a variable or a constant using the `d3.zoom()` method (or, in your case, `zoom()`):

```
const myZoom = zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    const transformation = getEvent().transform;
    const {x, y, k} = transformation;
    container.attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})scale(${k})`);
});
```

Here I'm using `myZoom` as the name just to make clear that it's different from `zoom()`, but the most traditional name is `zoom` (of course, you chan choose whatever valid name you want).

Then, you can use it as:

```
myZoom.scaleTo(container, zoomScale)
```

The main difference between using `myZoom.scaleTo(container, zoomScale)` and `zoom().scaleTo(container, zoomScale)` is that `myZoom` holds a reference to the event handlers and other methods in the chain, if any.

Also, don't forget to change the call in the SVG, which becomes just:

```
svg.call(myZoom);
```